# Regex expression to target phone number mask

Tags: javascript, regex

In React - I have an input mask that turns a user input into: (###) ###-####

Unfortunately, that data can't go to the DB in that format, so I need to strip the mask so it saves as ##########.  I'm trying to form a RegEx string to accomplish this in a string.replace to no avail.

I've tried a few attempts, and finally got it to remove the first paren '(', I thought adding the other characters I needed to remove would work as I go, but it's not.

```
const number = value.replace(/\([\(\)]\)/, "");
```

**TL;DR**

Can someone assist with a regular expression to turn `(###) ###-####` into `##########`?

Any supporting documentation as to **why** it works would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Keep in mind too that if you deal with international numbers you may need to consider a + sign as well. for future reference https://regexr.com is probably the best way to familiarize yourself with regex in a simple to use environment.

Comment: The [MDN documentation on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a good resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const value = '(123) 4348-43492'
const number = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

console.log(number);
```

Comment: `\D+` to improve performance if multiple non-digit characters are back to back

Comment: @ctwheels Although that's of course correct, it's unlikely to have it in a phone number and even if is the case, the performance difference would be negligible because the phone number string is too short. It is a good general advice, though. Comment upvoted.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  I'll accept as an answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @RacilHilan I completely agree, it is pretty negligible, but there is a parenthesis and space combination though; so it will improve performance parsing that part of the string.

Comment: @ctwheels Yes, you will gain 2 steps for the parenthesis and space combination. If it is international and you have a plus at the beginning, you will gain 2 more steps for the plus and parenthesis combination, so total of 4 steps. I cannot think of anything else :).

Answer (score 2):

How about replacing non-digits with `''`

```js
let value = "(111) 111-1111";

let number = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

console.log(number);
```

You could also use `/\D/g`

Comment: `\D` is the same as `[^\d]`

Comment: @ctwheels Cheers, added to my answer